# ¿Cómo convertir un .val capturado con jquery a double?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
var cantpa= $("#cantpa").val();
```

Me gustaría convertirlo a double, ¿Cuál sería la manera de convertirlo?

Answer (score 4):

En JavaScript existe la función [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/parseFloat) que:

> Convierte (parsea) un argumento de tipo cadena y devuelve un número de punto flotante.

Entonces lo único que tendrías que hacer es esto:

```
var cantpa= parseFloat( $("#cantpa").val() );
```

Comment: Por si queda alguna duda, la funcion `parseFloat` retorna un numero (type [`number`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-terms-and-definitions-number-value)) coma flotante de [IEEE-754 Double Precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) lo que es el equivalente a `double` en la mayoria de los lenguajes, osea de 64 bits.